# multiple if condition

Tags: objective-c, c

```
if ( ([mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"8"] == NO)  ||
    ([mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"9"] == NO) ) {
}
```

I wanna test if mobileNumber has prefix of 8 or 9. What am I doing wrong here?

ANSWER: Silly me, it should be AND condition instead of OR.

Comment: Can you debug what .text is sending you?

Comment: When my mobileNumber.text is "8" or "9", the condition is valid too. Which shouldnt be the case.

Comment: FWIW, `if (a == NO && b == NO)` is equivalent to `if (!(a || b))`. IOW, you could write: `if (!([mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"8"] || [mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"9"]))`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be

```
if(([mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"8"] == NO) && ([mobileNumber.text hasPrefix:@"9"] == NO)) {
  /* Mobile number does NOT have an 8 or 9 in the beginning */
}
```

My comment above is to make sure there isn't a `(` in front of the mobile number.

EDIT:
Did not quite understand what you were after.

Comment: I am checking for the condition whereby the mobileNumber.text doesn't have prefix of 8 or 9. changed to the YES to NO, which is the code I provided but to no avail.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense; I thought you were after seeing where the mobile number was either 8 or 9.  I edited the code above; should be what you are after (were there is no 8 or 9 in the prefix).

Comment: Yeah, that was silly. It should have been AND instead of OR. Figured that out but thanks anyway.